# Admob giving me ErrorCode: 1

Tags: android, admob

```
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 1
```

From logcat,

This is my code in Activity:

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-6122511777440087~4654564876");
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Lastly my string resource:

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-6122511777440087~4654564876</string>
```

What gives? I even tried a test ad and that didn't work. Same error code and same failure to load ad.

Comment: app id and app unit id should be different.
in your code seems to be same

Comment: Good catch. Got it working now

Comment: Happy to help :-).
if it works then please accept as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

app id and app unit id should be different. in your code seems to be same

here is full official description: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start